# change background if frame has no title

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, etoolbox

I would like to change my background canvas according to whether my frame has a title. This is the form I'm using (etoolbox):

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
   \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{1}{%
      % First frame
   }{%
      \ifnumequal{\c@framenumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}{
         % Last frame
      }{%
         %\if{\frametitle}{empty}{
         % Empty frames
        }{%  
           % Other frames
          }%
   }%
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not tested but, is `\ifstrempty{\beamer@frametitle}{<true>}{<false>}` what you are looking for?

Comment: That didn't work, I'm just getting the "false" background. code is now like this:
`\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
    \ifstrempty{beamer@frametitle}{
         % Empty frames
        }{%  
           % Other frames
          }%
}`
Don't really know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional `\ifx` to test for `\insertframetitle` to see if it's empty and act accordingly, A simple example adding an image with a "B" in frames with title, and an image with an "A" for frames with titles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\ifx\insertframetitle\@empty
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[opacity=0.2] at (current page.center) 
      {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[opacity=0.2] at (current page.center)   
      {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}};
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame with a title}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works like charm, even in my nested etoolbox statement.Thanks a lot.